# Pytorch Neural Network Trapped in Local Minimum

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I apologise in advance for the maths formatting - I do not have the reputation to post equations.

I have been using pytorch to build a neural network to learn the function,

f(x,y,t)=-x.10^y.cos(t)

but so far within a short number (~10) epochs the weights and biases all drop to 0 and never change from there. I believe this is because the network is stuck in a local minimum. The network is structured as:

```
    def __init__(self,learning_rate,beta_params):
    super(PINN, self).__init__()
    self.E_c=1.0

    self.lin1 = nn.Linear(3,20)
    self.lin2 = nn.Linear(20,20)
    self.lin3 = nn.Linear(20,20)
    self.lin4 = nn.Linear(20,20)
    self.lin5 = nn.Linear(20,1)

    self.optimizer = tr.optim.Adam(self.parameters(),lr=0.01)
    self.LossCrit = tr.nn.MSELoss()
    self.scaler=tr.cuda.amp.GradScaler()
```

with a forward function defined as:

```
    def forward(self, x):
    x = tr.sin(self.lin1(x))
    x = tr.tanh(self.lin2(x))
    x = tr.tanh(self.lin3(x))
    x = tr.tanh(self.lin4(x))
    x = self.lin5(x)

    return x
```

And the training cycle is defined as:

```
    def InitCycle(self, lb, ub, nTrain, batch_size):
    itNum = []
    itLoss = []
    for it in range(nTrain):
        #Choose a random selection of batch_size points from between lb and ub
        if it % 10 == 0:
            X_f = tr.rand((batch_size, 3)).cuda() * (ub - lb) + lb
            x = X_f[:,0:1]
            B_0 = tr.pow(10.0,X_f[:,2:3])
            t = X_f[:,1:2]
            
            #define a target
            f_Target = (- x * tr.cos(t))

        #zero the gradients and evaluate the prediction of the neural network
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        f_pred = self.forward(X_f)

        #define an 'output' which divides the neural network output by B_0 to keep all values close to unity and calculate loss and scaled gradients.
        output = f_pred / B_0
        loss = self.LossCrit(output,f_Target)
        self.scaler.scale(loss).backward()
       
        #record loss every 10 iterations
        if it % 10 == 0:
            if it > 0:
                itNum.append(np.log10(float(it)))
                itLoss.append(np.log10(loss.item()))
            print('loss at it. %d:  %.8e, lr at it. %d: %.2e' % (
            it, loss.item(), it, self.optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']))
        
        #update the weights and biases
        self.scaler.step(self.optimizer)
        self.scaler.update()
     
    #save the loss file at the end of the training run
    LFile = pd.DataFrame({'it#': itNum, 'Loss': itLoss})
    LFile.to_csv("PATH.csv")
```

I have tried every pytorch optimizer with various learning rates and hyperparameters but they all get stuck in the local minimum at {W,b}=0. I have also tried a different loss function which compares the reciprocals (with an added eps for numerical stability) but this also gets stuck at {W,b}=0.

The reason I am using gradient scaling is because with the default pytorch initialization my initial gradients are of the order 1E8 without scaling. I have tried using gradient clipping instead.

I've also tried to train a slightly different network to learn the function:

f(x,y,t)=-x.y.cos(t)

but this didn't work either so I stuck with the original form since I want the network to cover 6 orders of magnitude in 10^y and wanted to keep the values of the input y close to unity (y=-3->3).

I chose the sinusoidal activation function for the first layer in an effort to make it easier for the network to learn the cos(t) term but using a tanh activation function does not work either.

I am now out of ideas for how to get this to train and was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on the situation.